# CSS rules overriding with :not

Tags: css, rules, overriding

I have a question about CSS.
Actually, I have a html and css who look like this:

```css
.entry-content ul:not(.bxslider) > li {
  list-style-type: disc;
}
.... .woocommerce ul.products li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<body class="woocommerce">
  <div class="entry-content">
    <ul class="product">
      <li>Something</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

First, I thought that my first rule will by override by my second rule but after doing some test, my browser still applies the first one.

I would like to know why because I don't understand.

Comment: Rule of thumb, a given node will be receiving the most specific rule that applies to him. If the first rule is applied, it means that this rule is considered more specific than the second.

Comment: Voting to Close as this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score -1):

there is a typo error in `.woocommerce ul.products` instead of **products** use **product**

and here is your [working demo link](https://jsfiddle.net/xf3cdqrq/)

Comment: Typo is a close reason. You can mention the typo in a comment